# how to reset centering in media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have two divs wrapped around another div (id="about"). With a full size browser, it shows up centered horizontally AND vertically which is what I want. However, when window is resized smaller, I would like the two divs to stack up on top of each other instead of side by side.

For my attempt, I want to basically reset that wrapper (about). My CSS:

```
#icon{
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;

    max-width: 200px;
}
#about{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;  

    <!-- These two lines horizontally and vertically centers about -->
    <!-- If removed, its responsive and stacks up the way that I want,
         BUT it no longer is centered vertically and sits on top of the page -->
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#aboutInfo{
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;  
    padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){      
    #icon {
        max-width: 100px;
    }
    <!-- ATTEMPT TO RESET -->
    #about {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }       
}
```

How do I reset the centering so that it stacks up when the window is resized but still have it centered in larger browsers. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="about">

        <div class="col-sm-4 padding-0">
            <img src="img/html5.png" id="icon">
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-6 padding-0">
            <div id="aboutInfo">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> 
                  Suspendisse malesuada lacus commodo enim varius, <br> non gravida ipsum faucibus. 
                  Vivamus pretium pulvinar <br> elementum. In vehicula ut elit vitae dapibus. 
                  Cras ipsum <br> neque, finibus id mattis vehicula, rhoncus in mauris. 
                  In <br> hendrerit vitae velit vel consequat. Duis eleifend dui vel <br> tempor 
                  maximus. Aliquam rutrum id dolor vel ullamcorper. <br> Nunc cursus sapien 
                  a ex porta dictum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div> <!-- end of about -->
    </div> <-- end of row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
body {margin: 0}

#icon {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-width: 200px;
}

#about {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* added */
}

#aboutInfo {
  border: 2px solid red; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {      
  #icon {max-width: 100px}
  #about {flex-direction: column} /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="about">
      <div class="col-sm-4 padding-0">
        <img id="icon" src="https://placehold.it/200x150" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 padding-0">
        <div id="aboutInfo">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> 
            Suspendisse malesuada lacus commodo enim varius, <br> non gravida ipsum faucibus. 
            Vivamus pretium pulvinar <br> elementum. In vehicula ut elit vitae dapibus. 
            Cras ipsum <br> neque, finibus id mattis vehicula, rhoncus in mauris. 
            In <br> hendrerit vitae velit vel consequat. Duis eleifend dui vel <br> tempor 
            maximus. Aliquam rutrum id dolor vel ullamcorper. <br> Nunc cursus sapien 
            a ex porta dictum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end of about -->
  </div> <!-- end of row -->
</div>
```

By default *flex-container* or *parent* stacks *flex-items* or *children* row-wise, but you can change that easily with the `flex-direction` *property* set to the *value* of `column`.